# Need help reaching a variable in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, variables, namespaces, declaration

Can someone please help me understand the scoop of JavaScript variables, and how to reach them?

Imagine the following...

```
// Namespace declaration
var p = {};

p.result = {

    searchForm: $('#search-form'),
    searchAction: this.searchForm.attr('action'),

    anotherSection: {
        hello: 'Hello ',
        world: this.hello + 'world!'
    }

}
```

This won't work, and it gives the error saying `this.searchForm` is undefined. The same error appears in `anotherSection` as well (ofc).

How can I declare a variable in terms of another variable inside the same namespace?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `this` keyword is bound to the *function-context*, you can't use it in object literals like that.

You could, make functions as "getters":

```
var p = {};
p.result = {
  searchForm: $('#search-form'),
  getSearchAction: function () {
    return this.searchForm.attr('action');
  },
  anotherSection: {
    hello: 'Hello ',
    getWorld: function () {
      return this.hello + 'world!';
    }
  }
};
```

Comment: +1 for the edit and code example. I think this looks like a good solution :)

Comment: You could optimize it using `this.getWorld = this.hello + 'world!'; return this.getWorld` so that it only concatenates the string the first time it gets called.

Answer (score 3):

There is no way to refer to an object literal as you're building it.

You need to write the following:

```
p.result = {
    searchForm: $('#search-form'),
    anotherSection: {
        hello: 'Hello '
    }
}

p.result.searchAction = p.result.searchForm.attr('action');
p.result.anotherSection.world = p.result.anotherSection.hello + 'world!';
```

Comment: +1 thanks, but I'll go for the solution provided by CMS this time.

Answer (score 1):

You can't access the properties of an object inside its own literal — they don't exist yet.

Answer (score 0):

**this** is an object, so when you use **this.searchForm**, you are accessing a property of the **this** object. You just want to access a variable, so you can just use **searchForm**.